# How to get the particular dates of a week between two selected month dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone help me to obtain the `dates` between two `selected month dates`.If I have a `start date` as `04-Sep-2013` and `end date` as `10-Nov-2013`,How can i get the `dates` between these two dates in a `weekly` manner,means i need the resulting dates to be `04 Sept 2013`, `11 Sept 2013`, `18 Sept 2013`,`25 Sept 2013`,`Oct 2 2013` so on,like this manner.Or simplying the question If the `starting date` `04-Sep-2013` is a `wednesday` i need all the dates of `wednesdays` between these `two selected dates`.

Comment: Are you dealing with `Date` objects? Have you looked at a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your start date add 7 days to the date until the date you get is greater than or equal to your end date.

Here's a fiddle to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/n8xTU/

```
var start = new Date('04-Sep-2013');
var end = new Date('10-Nov-2013');

var tmp = start;

while(end > tmp)
{
   console.log(tmp);
   tmp.setDate(tmp.getDate()+7);
}
```

Comment: tanx for the reply @john but how can i add 7 when it reaches a date say 30 oct 2013..??

Comment: i modified the code. it will add 7 days to the time until it reaches the end.  I'm not adding to the day part of the date, I'm adding to the date as a whole, so if it's at the end of the month it will roll over to the next month.

Comment: Oh tanx for your help @john.U r the best... :)

Comment: just modified it back to the way it was, it works that way best. adding whole days instead of 7 * ms in a day makes it work even through the daylight savings time change.